# Pegando apenas o atributo "src"

Tags: php

dentro do meu sistema, ele deve pegar apenas o atributo "src" de dentro de uma variavel e colocar em uma nova, segue o exemplo:

```
//<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Funiladmag%2Fvideos%2F4623781360978220%2F&show_text=0&width=476" width="476" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
$iFrame = $_POST['vid_iframe'];
```

Como que faria para pegar apenas o que está dentro do "src"? Tentei usar um explode porém não funcionou.

Comment: Usando jQuery, você pode fazer  `$('.embed-responsive-item').attr('src')` e recuperar o atributo do iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se for em php e sua string for o iframe faz assim

```
$variavel='<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Funiladmag%2Fvideos%2F4623781360978220%2F&show_text=0&width=476" width="476" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>';

$var=explode('src="',$variavel);
$var=explode('"',$var['1']);
echo $var['0'];
```